# Node+MongoDB: find in collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, find

I just don't know why it's not working(( val.instruments is undefinded.

```
function getInstruments(callback) {
    db.collection("settings", function(error, settings) {
        settings.find({ "settings" : "settings" }, function (err, val) {
            console.log('from getInstruments ' + val.instruments);
            if (val.instruments==undefined) {
                callback("");
            } else {
                callback(val.instruments);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

scheme:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "508677a3e5089a6df291631a"
    },
    "settings": "settings",
    "instruments": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3"
    ]
}
```

returns:

```
node app.js:
from getInstruments undefined
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

**UPD**: Modified code to:

```
function getInstruments(callback) {
db.collection("settings", function(error, settings) {
    settings.find({ "settings" : "settings" }).toArray(function(err, docs) {
       console.dir(docs.instruments);
    });
});
}
```

Result:

```
[ { _id: 508677a3e5089a6df291631a,
settings: 'settings',
instruments: [ '1', '2', '3' ] } ]
```

Changed to:

```
function getInstruments(callback) {
    db.collection("settings", function(error, settings) {
        settings.find({ "settings" : "settings" }).toArray(function(err, docs) {
           console.dir(docs.instruments);
        });
    });
}
```

Result:

```
undefined
```

How it can be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find is returning an array.  So you should check that val.length is greater than 0 and then look at val[0].instruments

Comment: The problem is find is returning nothing. It just can't find my object

Comment: I didn't see in your note that val is undefined.  I just see that val.instruments is undefined.  Did you try to output just val ?

Comment: Yeah, it returns an object and logs it in a plain-text. Well, actually, it seems it can find an object, but I can't get ["1", "2", "3"] in output.

Comment: after your console.log, do a console.dir(val) and tell me what that prints

Comment: As I understand it prints an object/collection tree

Comment: It appears that your update has the same code with different results so I assume it is a copy and paste problem. If the first code is printing out docs (and not docs.instruments), you can see that docs results is a JSON array of objects (1 object in this case) so docs.instruments will be undefined however docs[0].instruments will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the example at the very end of the [find section](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#find) of the docs.  If you run `val.toArray()` within the callback to `find`, you should be able to loop over the returned docs and process them one by one.